# How to hide outer bounded parent rectangle in GEF figure

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am trying to create a circle or an ellipse in GEF framework. We are setting constraints/bounds as a rectangle within which the circle/ellipse sits.
My problem is that I am not able to hide/suppress outer Rectangle when I do drag drop or I just click on the circle. Is there any way we can remove this outer Rectangle  ? any tip idea would help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rectangle is created by the `NonResizableEditPolicy` (or `ResizableEditPolicy` if your figure is resizable). This policy is added automatically to children of some layout policies, for example children of `ConstrainedLayoutEditPolicy`. What you need to do is find which layout policy you are using in your container, and override it to use a different edit policy to decorate the children of the container. This can be done by overriding the `NonResizableEditPolicy` (or `ResizableEditPolicy`) and then modify how this policy provides feedback when the `Figure` is selected, clicked on, etc.